# Alternative for InternetSetOption in winRT

Tags: proxy, network-programming, windows-store-apps, winrt-component

Is there any alternative to Set/Get proxy settings in winRT. I need to implement this for a windows store App. I found this link (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464945.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 ) but there is nothing mentioned about retrieving proxy settings.

Thanks,
Kunal